# What is the difference between 目前 and 現在?

Tags: difference

In my research, 目前 and 現在 seem all mean now or present.

So native speakers or Chinese advanced learners, is there any difference between 目前 and 現在?

Answer (score 5):

The pair of words "目前" and "現在" draws parallel to "for the time being" and "now" in English. In many circumstances you can use them interchangeably, but in some cases, "目前" has an additional implication that that the current conditions are subject to change ***shortly***. If you want to use a stronger word than "目前" to stress that the situation is volatile, use "暫時" ("provisionally") instead.

Answer (score 4):

目前=in current condition

现在=now

they've just got some slight difference, in most of the time they are interchangeable.

Answer (score 4):

目前 and 现在 have the same meaning

Differences:

1. Formality, 目前 is **far more formal**;
2. Object, to describe "people nowadays", use 现在 (i.e. 目前的人 sounds weird). To describe phenomenon (e.g. market price, weather), both are okay.